# After and Before pseudo element not working in Safari Browser

Tags: css, safari, pseudo-element

I installed safari 5.1 on my windows and i tested my website on it
but all the after and before that i used in my css not shown.

for example this is my css code:

```
.block ul.list > li > a:before {
    content: "\f104";
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 600;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.250em;
}
```

its working in chrome and ie but in my safari not.

i tried to add "position: absolute" but nothing changed.
i tried to use double :: but the same.

what can i do ?

tnx a lot

Comment: why check on safari 5.1 ? nobody uses that anymore. i can't event find a code editor that works with safari 5.1 ( jsfiddle and codepen not working )

Comment: @MihaiT so what the minimum version that you are recommend to check?